# Replace only framework.jar & its relevant libraries on Android MarshMallow

Tags: java, android, android-source

Anyone know steps to replace frameworks.jar and relevant libraries on Android Marshmallow device?

My work is to modify Android Marshmallow framework source code, do full-build then update to device then verify result. It takes about 1,2 hours each time.

It is OK if I do it 1,2,3 times but actually I had to repeat it even 100 times if my modification not work. But I only modify only a small piece of code in frameworks/ so I think it would save me much time if I can rebuild only frameworks/ module in Android code and replace only frameworks/ part in device.

I know how to use `mmm` to rebuild just frameworks/ module. But I don' know how to replace frameworks/ part in device because just replace frameworks.jar not work in Marshmallow case.

Comment: Which part of the "frameworks/" are you modifying? There is a lot of modules there. For example, the framework.jar comes from the Android.mk located at "frameworks/base" repository.

Comment: Hi @robin-chander, I edited my original answer with more details, check if it helps you.

Comment: @Perazzo - I will test your suggesstions. Since I made changes to java code only - I was pushing framework.jar and it worked on KK and L. I'll test if pushing libs make a difference on M

Comment: If you are modifying only Java code, probably only JARs are going to be affected. Which classes did you change? We could try to track which makefiles cover them.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you're modifying things under [`frameworks/base/`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/marshmallow-release), as it's where `framework.jar` comes from, the steps I use are:

1. If you already have a full-build, use `mm` command in the directory where you're modifying any code. It's faster than `mmm` since it doesn't compile framework dependencies again.
2. Go to `<aosp-root>/out/target/product/<product-name>/system/framework/` directory and get `framework.jar` and `services.jar` items.
3. Go to `<aosp-root>/out/target/product/<product-name>/system/lib/` directory and get any `libandroid*.so` file.
4. With device already rooted, `adb push *.jar /system/framework/.`
5. `adb push *.so /system/lib/.`
6. Factory reset the device and reboot it.

Changes made on your framework might work now. If your target device is 64 bits, replace lib by lib64 on above destinations.

### **Explanation**

Above steps will vary according to what we modify inside AOSP framework. Here a quick description on what goes inside each file:

- `framework.jar`: APIs accessible to applications
- `services.jar`: Implementation of managers and system services located under `frameworks/base/services`.
- `libandroid*.so`: Libraries generated from native code (C/C++) like the .cpp files located at `frameworks/base/core/jni`.

But, in general, each `Android.mk` inside frameworks will generate at least one output named by the `LOCAL_MODULE` variable and the type of the module depends on the following include instruction:

```
# JAR file
include $(BUILD_JAVA_LIBRARY)

# Library to be used by other modules
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Executables
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

For example, the [`frameworks/base/cmds`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/marshmallow-release/cmds/) folder generates a Java library and an executable for each item inside it, like the `pm` command commonly used to install apps via ADB. In any case, the rule is: Java libraries go to `/system/framework/`, Shared libraries go to `/system/lib/` and executables go to `/system/bin`.

More official information about `Android.mk` can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/android_mk.html#var), but it doesn't cover all variables and macros used by Android Build System, I get most of that info from AOSP code itself.

Hope it helps.